# How to pull Azure Cognitive Search Quota and usage?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to pull azure cognitive search current and quota .
[image]

Can anyone help me on:
" how can I get that information to csv using some service principle."

I found one link to pull this kind of data :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-service-statistics

But I am not sure how to use this api to get above screenshot information.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is the correct way to do it, it returns all the information you need.

It looks like this endpoint does not support OAuth2 & RBAC. So instead of using service principal, you need to provide the admin api-key in the request header.

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-api-keys?tabs=portal-use%2Cportal-find%2Cportal-query#find-existing-keys) how to access the api-key. If you'll be doing that from a powershell script, you can authenticate with your service principal and fetch the key using Get-AzSearchAdminKeyPair, then use this key to make a http request to get the statistics and finally convert them to CSV format.

Comment: but do we need admin access for this type of data pull

Comment: Using the api-key, yes, it needs to be admin key and you need at least contributor / Search Service Contributor roles to read the API Key unfortunately. It's not really following the principle of least privilege :)

Comment: However, check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-rbac?tabs=config-svc-portal%2Croles-portal%2Ctest-portal%2Ccustom-role-portal%2Cdisable-keys-portal#built-in-roles-used-in-search

Looks like the RBAC support for Reader is now in preview and "this allows you to read search metrics, content metrics (storage consumed, number of objects)". This doc says RBAC is supported in all Search REST APIs, but it's contradictory to the API specification which says the api key is required. 
It's worth trying I think, maybe the API doc is not updated yet.